# How to avoid eval when accessing object properties?

Tags: javascript, properties, eval

I've read quite a lot but I can't figure out the following:

```
var eventCity = [
    {date: 'Apr 11 2017', type: 'alpha'},
    {date: 'Apr 26 2017', type: 'beta'}
];

var currentCity = 'eventCity';  // this is generated dynamically

var aDate = eval(currentCity)[0].date;
```

How to avoid the use of `eval()` maintaining the same result ( `aDate = 'Apr 11 2017'` ) ?

Comment: What other values could `currentCity` possibly have, and to what should it evaluate then? Why/where is it generated dynamically?

Comment: Why not just dynamically generate `var currentCity = eventCity;` and drop the `eval`?

Comment: @Bergi I'm writing a Chrome extension. In the code there are var `eventCity1`, var `eventCity2`, ... and so for. The user select which eventCity she wants to see and this value is passed to the code above. For code readability I rather maintain the var `currentCity` if possible.

Comment: You really should not do that. Make an **array** of `eventCities`, and a `currentCityIndex` that holds an integer. Then do `var currentCity = eventCities[currentCityIndex]`

Comment: I've finally gone with Nina's answer below, which works wonders! Thanks for your comments @Bergi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use an object and take the dynamic value as key?

```
var object = {
        eventCity: [
            { date: 'Apr 11 2017', type: 'alpha' },
            { date: 'Apr 26 2017', type: 'beta' }
        ]
    },
    currentCity = 'eventCity',  // this is generated dynamically
    aDate = object[currentCity][0].date;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks @nina  : )

Answer (score 0):

> var options = []
>
> options['eventCity']=[
>       {date: 'Apr 11 2017', type: 'alpha'},
>       {date: 'Apr 26 2017', type: 'beta'} ];